# How to implement two empty views in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a view with `TabHost` and `TabWidget` which host on every tab a ListView. I need to have an `empty` view for every ListView. That is on every tab, if corresponding ListView has no items, I need to display another view.

If I have a single tab with a view marked by `@android:id/empty` id in the layout xml-file, it works perfectly well. But how can the same thing be accomplished for each tab?

I prefer a simple solution with minimum coding. I'd wish Android support something like `@android:id/empty1` and `@android:id/empty2`, but it doesn't.

UPDATE: It's solved. Custom IDs work ok for empty views as well. It was my misunderstanding that only preconfigured Android views with specific ID can serve as empty view.

Comment: Do you know you can post and accept your own answers? Doing that is preferable to popping an update into the question to say you solved this. The question will get closed as Too Localised which may have a negative effect on your future ability to ask new questions. Cheers.

Comment: @Kev, of course I know this and I did this several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After short investigation I found out, that custom IDs work ok for empty views as well. It was my misunderstanding that only preconfigured Android views with specific ID can serve as empty view.